# glm.nb with random effect as matrix

Tags: r, offset, glm, phylogeny

I am analyzing gene expression data in `R`. I would like to test for differences in expression when accounting for the phylogenetic effect.
I can run GLM with a negative binomial distribution and normalization factor as an offset:

```
library(MASS)
glm.nb(expression ~ Group + offset(log(normFactor)), data=data)
```

However, I don't know how to include phylogenetic effect in this model. I can obtain a variance-covariance or correlation matrix from my phylogeny:

```
library(ape)
tree <- read.tree("tree.nwk")    
varCovMatrix <- vcv(tree, model = "Brownian", cor = FALSE)
```

I found that lmekin allows to specify the variance-covariance structure of the random effects:

```
library(coxme)
lmekin(expression ~ Group + (1| animal) + offset(log(normFactor)), data=data, varlist= varCovMatrix)
```

But I cannot specify negative binomial distribution and it isn't clear whether it understands offset.
The same problem is for `MCMCglmm`.

Please, help me to put into one GLMM:

- the variance-covariance matrix
- normalization factor as an offset
- negative binomial distribution

Comment: this is an interesting question.  I would add a bounty, but I'm afraid no-one really has a very good answer.  (I don't know if I could salvage my bounty by posting an incomplete answer.)